# Microwave more than one container at a time

Tags: microwave

If package says to microwave 7 minutes for one container, how long for three?
I want to cook all three packages at one time but it doesn't give me multiple microwaving times. Microwave shouldn't be multiplied by three, I know that.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to microwave them all together (rotating every once in a while) until they're warmed, then finish each one individually.

Answer (score 6):

There's no general answer. As you say, it's probably less than triple the time for one, and unless it's really small, it's probably substantially more than the time for one. But depending on the size and shape, it could be all over the place in that range.

You pretty much just have to try it and check periodically, starting perhaps after 10-15 minutes to get an idea. If it's relatively large compared to your microwave, you may also need to rearrange them periodically to get even heating, maybe every several minutes, in which case you'll get a very good idea how fast it's heating and don't have to worry about all the rest of this.

Comment: definitely re-arrange. I foresee burnt and over-cooked edges if the OP doesn't.